# Intermittent Lightning out CORS issue with external site

Tags: lightning-out, cors

I'm running into a CORS issue with a lightning out component running on an external website where Salesforce appears to be redirecting to the visualforce domain to load lightning out and not respecting my CORS whitelisting in SF.

I'm seeing the usual CORS error (see below) in browser console. However, if I log in to that SF org as a regular user and go to the page that's giving a CORS error SF does not redirect and seems to respect CORS.

non-working redirect flow that throws CORS error
[image: redirect flow before loading page]

Page I go to:
https://membershiporg--slpartial.lightning.force.com/c/SL_InquiryApp.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT

working flow w/no CORS error
[image: new flow]

CORS error:

> Failed to load
>   https://membershiporg--slpartial.lightning.force.com/c/SL_InquiryApp.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT:
>
> Redirect from
>   'https://membershiporg--slpartial.lightning.force.com/c/SL_InquiryApp.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT'
>
> to
>   'https://membershiporg--slpartial.cs67.my.salesforce.com/visualforce/session?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmembershiporg--slpartial.lightning.force.com%2Fc%2FSL_InquiryApp.app%3Faura.format%3DJSON%26aura.formatAdapter%3DLIGHTNING_OUT'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy:
>
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'https://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: can you please add screenshot of your CORS settings ?

Comment: Hi @Greg , were you able to resolve this? I have a similar problem here -> https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254557/lightning-out-cors-error-even-after-whitelisting-force-com-site

Comment: Hi @Greg ,Have you resolved it, I am facing the same issue now. And your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: @VitaliiDehnerys, It's been many years so can't recall but does my answer in Samuel's linked question help?

Comment: thanks for answering @GregGrinberg, I have already resolved it with this question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/378152/lightning-out-getting-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-t